# check image for corruption

Tags: php, imagick, corruption

I download an image using wget and using php imagick for create thumbnail version of image.
My image is this:

[image]

As you see my image download but as corrupted image. how can i figure it out using php imagick this image corrupted.

Comment: Use this http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.valid.php

Comment: @crypticツ i used this before not work well at all.